# The lightest 26" mountain bike tire with minimum width of 2.3

Tags: tire, weight

All mountain or xc application, wet or dry condition.

Comment: -1: Not a real question and shows complete lack of research - took me less than a minute to find the answer. Tires are always a trade off between weight, performance in various conditions and durability. The only thing you have left out of the question is durability.

Comment: A little curious as to why one would care that much.  Especially for off-road, the weigh of the tire would be way down on my list of criteria.

Comment: If you are worried about weight, why on earth are you putting 2.3" tires on. I can see very little benefit from a lightly constructed 2.3 over a 2.1 with decent construction.

Comment: This is a real question. I care about weight, and i want the best downhill traction with ability to climb fast, hence big tire low weight. The weight of tire and wheel set is high on my list, this is where many people are wrong, the weight of wheel set and tires are the first to go when trying to lighten up a bike for off road.

Answer (score 4):

According to [weight weenies](http://weightweenies.starbike.com/listings/components.php?type=mtbtyres&sortby=real)the  Continental Speed King Supersonic is the lightest 2.3 or larger tire.

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty unlikely that anyone keeps a list of weights for all the available tyres by width.  Your best idea is to download the datasheets of brands/models you consider good enough (quality wise) and then compare the weights.

Comment: +1 Normally I would agree - but when it comes to bicycles and  weight - thats almost a religion........ weight weenies have a list (probably not complete, but it's a start)

Comment: The reason i use this site is that i do not have time to research this info, and plenty of people can help answer my question, thats why i am here.